# For loop vs While loop - dutch flag

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, go, while-loop

I'm trying to implement the dutch national flag problem using for loop and while loop in golang.

Problem statement -
For a given array arrange the elements in such a way that element greater than the pivot are in right side of the pivot and elements less than the array are in the left side of the array.
Example -

Input - [3 2 4 1 6 3 7 5] , pivot = 4

Output - [3 2 1 3 4 7 5 6]

For loop implementation [ NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    in := []int{3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5}
    pivot := 4
    run(in, pivot)

}

func run(in []int, pivot int) {

    fmt.Println("before : ", in)

    lBoundary := 0

    hBoundary := len(in) - 1

    for i := 0; i <= hBoundary; i++ {
        if in[i] > pivot {
            in[i], in[hBoundary] = in[hBoundary], in[i]
            hBoundary--
        } else if in[i] < pivot {
            in[i], in[lBoundary] = in[lBoundary], in[i]
            lBoundary++
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("after: ", in)

}
```

While loop implementation [ WORKING AS EXPECTED] -

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    in := []int{3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5}
    pivot := 4
    run(in, pivot)

}

func run(in []int, pivot int) {

    fmt.Println("before : ", in)

    i := 0
    lBoundary := 0

    hBoundary := len(in) - 1

    for i <= hBoundary {
        if in[i] > pivot {
            in[i], in[hBoundary] = in[hBoundary], in[i]
            hBoundary--
        } else if in[i] < pivot {
            in[i], in[lBoundary] = in[lBoundary], in[i]
            lBoundary++
            i++
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("after: ", in)
}
```

I'm not able to identify the problem in for loop implementation.

Comment: Post your code. And if you want to use the playground: Use the official one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in case of while you update the while loop counter `i` only for two conditions i.e

```
    else if in[i] < pivot {
        in[i], in[lBoundary] = in[lBoundary], in[i]
        lBoundary++
        i++
    } else {
        i++
    }
```

But in case of for loop you the counter gets incremented each time the loop is executed because of `i++`.

Hence, if you update your for loop code to place the increment condition inside the loop, it will behave as intended:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    in := []int{3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5}
    pivot := 4
    run(in, pivot)

}

func run(in []int, pivot int) {

    fmt.Println("before : ", in)

    lBoundary := 0

    hBoundary := len(in) - 1
    // remove i++ condition
    for i := 0; i <= hBoundary; {
        if in[i] > pivot {
            in[i], in[hBoundary] = in[hBoundary], in[i]
            hBoundary--  // no increment in this condition
        } else if in[i] < pivot {
            in[i], in[lBoundary] = in[lBoundary], in[i]
            lBoundary++
            i++  // add the increment condition here
        } else {
            i++ // and here as well
        }

    }

    fmt.Println("after: ", in)

}
```